# when I select print all, I get a print dialog. If I select cancel, It will still print

Tags: excel, vba

I am using an Excel 2010 VBA to do a lookup and print individual pages of the names and pictures in the other worksheet. When I select print all as i have created a command button for that, I get the printer dialog so I can select the appropriate printer. If I select the correct printer, the pages print perfectly. My problem is if I select cancel on the printer dialog, the pages will still print. How can I make this stop if I select cancel?

```
Private Sub PrintAll_Click()

    Dim rngOffenders As Range
    Set rngOffenders = Worksheets("Names").Range("A2",Worksheets("Names").Range("A2").End(xlDown))

    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show

    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In rngOffenders.Cells
        Worksheets("Template").Range("LastName").Value = rng.Value
        Calculate
        Worksheets("Template").PrintOut
    Next rng

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show
> ```

`.Show` is a *function*, which means it *returns a value* - a `Boolean` value, as shown in the Object Browser (<kbd>F2</kbd>):

[image: Object Browser showing members of Excel.Dialog]

Your code is currently discarding that value, and the rest of the procedure executes unconditionally.

You need to capture that return value in a variable:

```
Dim willPrint As Boolean
willPrint = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show
```

You then have several options to handle cancellation; simplest might be to just `Exit Sub` when the result is `False`:

```
If Not willPrint Then Exit Sub 'dialog was cancelled: bail out
```

Comment: Worked like a charm...Thank you

Comment: @Mat'sMug deleted the WRONG answer, but found something weird. If I select few cells on the sheet and then call ` bResult = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show(, , , , , Selection) `, Excel gets stuck in loop, no matter what I click, dialog keeps re-appearing. Not sure why, but its just weird. :)